# combination of data from files and plotting in r software

Tags: r, combinations

I have 102 text files, each containing of same type of data. Suppose data it is stored in variable d1 of the file f1.

In R:
I want to make plot between data in two files. say d1 vs d2 or d45 vs d85

I need to do these for all combinations ( 102C2 combinations)

How do I do that?

Comment: What are you going to do with 5,000+ plots?

Comment: lolz..I dont know my professor want them.. You have any solution?

Comment: Ah... the old data fishing exercise I presume. There's got to be a significant correlation in there somewhere.

Comment: yes...need to do correlations
solution?

Comment: maybe your prof is testing you like The Karate Kid... Has he also asked that you wash his car?

Comment: @flodel - `wax <- "off"; if(wax=="on") wax <- "off" else if (wax=="off") wax <- "on";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of an out there request, as there is no way you would be able to make sense of that many plots. E.g.:

```
ncol(combn(1:102,2))
```

Gives a total of ***5151*** plots for the unique combinations between the 102 sets of data. If your professor wants to manually search through all those plots, he better pour himself a large coffee. I would seriously reconsider what you are trying to find out from this data and maybe redefine the scope of your investigation.

With that said, here's some potential code that may or not be good advice given the circumstances. In fact, I'll go so far as to suggest not running the below code with all of your files lest your computer explode.

```
# This is how you would read text files into a list,
# courtesy of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9110110/496803):
# raw <- list.files(pattern="*.txt")
# listy <- lapply(raw, read.table)

# set up some mock data instead
listy <- list(1:3,4:6,7:9)

# get every possible combination
combos <- combn(1:length(listy),2)

# define a function to plot each combination of data  
multiplot <- function(x) {
    dev.new()
    plot(listy[[(x[1])]],listy[[x[2]]])
}

# Generate the plots separately.
# This will probably kill your R session with
# the number of plots you are generating.

apply(combos,2,multiplot)
```

Comment: I also want to make correlation matrix for this data.
can help?

Comment: ?cor will give you what you want. You have to put all of them in a big matrix/dataframe first though.

Comment: Hey guys please vote up my question I am not able to ask any questions...
Please do it